# Automatically add Regions to code

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, automation, regions

I've been looking for a method to format my cs files.

I have already written a code that I have decided that needs to be cleaned and sorted into regions but it takes a really long time and effort to format all the cs files.

Is there any automation tool, dll, visual studio extension, etc that can be used to make some basic regions like Private Members, Public Methods, Ctors, etc...

Note: *Snippets don't help in this case*

Comment: When you begin thinking along these lines that's a sign of some serious code smell.  Think OOP.  Think single responsibility.  Think SOLID.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design).  Your code should never be so unwieldy that you would ever consider needing a tool to automate breaking it into reasons.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: *regions ... sorry, just realized my typo.

Comment: The project IS solid. But I have many files that I want to add regions to, even if they are really slim and tiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @aaron-palmer on this, but if you really want to do it, Resharper cleanup templates can be used to add in regions